# How do I send an Invoke-restMethod

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to get an authentication toke from a REST API and I appear to have difficulty in sending - well anything apparently. This site requires the Id and password be sent in clear text in the body of the request (curl version):

```
curl -X POST "https://somehost.myplace.com/api/v2/authorize" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"123@my_place\", \"cookie\": true, \"csrfToken\": false}"
```

In PowerShell I have this code:

```
$headers = @{
    'accept'='application/json';
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
}
$auth_data = @{ 'username'='root';
    'password'='123@my_place';
    'cookie'=$true;
    'csrfToken'=$false
}
$LoginResponse = ""
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://somehost.myplace.com/api/v2/authorize' -Headers $headers -Body $auth_data -Method 'POST'
```

When I set the -Method to 'POST' I get the following error:

```
{"message":{"text":"Invalid request.","key":"error.400","developerMessage":"Parsing JSON body failed."},"code":400,"status":"error","responseTime":"2020-05-11T14:28:36.836Z","apiVersion":"2.2","data":{}}
```

If I use the default 'GET' I get this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"message":{"text":"GET https://somehost.myplace.com/api/v2/authorize?csrfToken=False\u0026cookie=True\u0026username=root\u0026password=123%40my_place does not match a valid endpoint.","key":"error.405","developerMessage":"Route does not match, double-check the URL."},"code":405,"status":"error","responseTime":"2020-05-11T15:01:49.360Z","apiVersion":"2.2","data":{}}
```

I believe the issue is with the u0026 in front of the user name and password then the substitution of @ with the %40.

I need a nudge if you would.

Answer (score 0):

So this has been a bear. The REST API is expecting the ID and password to be in the body of the POST request and in the format of user: , password:  so I had to load a string with that information and use it in the Invoke-RESTMethod with -Body